# node_module folder not appear in working directory

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am a beginner with Node.js. I've created a directory and ran these commands with VS Code terminal:

```sh
npm init   
npm install
```

But the `node_modules` directory does not appear in the working directory.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: You probably need to install an actual package for the folder to get created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i assume that you use expressjs as middleware of nodejs

so try to hit this command on your terminal

> npm init

this create a package.json for your project and then hit this command in you terminal

> npm install express --save

express install in your working directory and --save entry in your package file

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem. As @JBallin suggested in his comment, the `npm install` command will only create the `node_modules` directory if there are some packages to be installed. Since you haven't add any dependencies to your project, there is nothing to place in the `node_modules` and NPM will not create it. It will be automatically created once you add any dependencies.